# What to do if a Distribution Provisioning Profile has expired and I want to update my app?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

More than one year ago I submitted an app. Now I want to update it, but my Distribution Provisioning Profile has expired.

So I created a new one. But then I came across this warning:

> When you are submitting an update of your application to iTunes
>   Connect for App Store distribution, make sure to:
>
> Use the same Distribution Provisioning Profile to build each new
>   version of your application

Unfortunately I completely changed my development machine in the meantime, so the old expired provisioning profile doesn't exist anymore on my machine. Organizer window doesn't show it, therefore.

The iOS Provisioning Portal doesn't offer an option to re-enable expired Distribution Provisioning Profiles. So all I was able to do was create a new one instead. So does that mean I can't update my app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Juste create a new certificate, as long as you do not change the bundleID you should be able to send the update.

When you create a new or renew an appstore provisioning profile you can select the new certificate and you are good to go.

Comment: Created a certificate, but I don't see a way to renew the distribution provisioning profile. There is a button to "Modify" it which does show the new cert. So do we do Modify, then submit?

Comment: Yes, just select the new certificate and recreate the profile.

Comment: Do I have to rebuild and reupload my apps if they are already in the app store?

Comment: @LittleTinyDev Did you reuploaded the build?

Answer (score 2):

SEPT- 2013

I just had this issue and this is what I did:

1. Click on the expired Provisioning Profile in
   https://developer.apple.com and choose Edit.
2. You'll notice instructions for creating a new certSigningRequest and
   certificate, follow those exactly.
3. You can then easily upload the generated certificative which will re-activate the profile.

No need to delete anything.